How does the description of the rules rules file use the data of the node_exporter in prometheus alertmanager monitoring
When I send an alert, I expect to send a push when the alert is triggered
I would like to add more information in the description, such as node_filesystem_files_free & node_cpu_seconds_total & node_cpu_guest_seconds_total
groups:
  - name: test
    rules:
      - alert: test
        expr: (node_filesystem_free_bytes{job="big-data"} / 1024^3) < 10
        for: 1m
        labels:       
          name: instance
          severity: Critical
          level: Warning
          job: big-data
        annotations:
          summary: "test - {{ $labels.appname }}"
          description: "{{ $labels.device }} 10GB! \n last: {{ $value | printf \"%.1f\" }} GB"
          value: "{{ $value}}%"

When I try to use
description: "{{ node_filesystem_free_bytes }}"
error :  function "node_filesystem_free_bytes" not defined

I look at the examples, are relatively simple, I want to add more data about the early warning node, for example, in the case of insufficient hard disk resources, the early warning information to add the CPU usage

In this example, since value you want is basically result of the query, you can use {{ $value }}. But if you want to add value of different metric, you might try templating function query - it allows to add arbitrary query result to alert, but is quite tricky to use.

Maybe you could find some help here or in this answer (it doesnt answer question their, but more or less does here).

tks dude @markalex

Prometheus makes it easy  to define alerting rules, Alerting rules allow you to define alert conditions based on Prometheus expression, language expressions and to send notifications about firing alerts to an external service.
Maybe issues with incorrect usage of function syntax in Prometheus templates. From this grafana document you can find various prometheus alerting rules. Check this below section from the document
alert: HostDiskWillFillIn24Hours
    expr: (node_filesystem_avail_bytes * 100) / node_filesystem_size_bytes < 10 and ON (instance, device, mountpoint) predict_linear(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{fstype!~"tmpfs"}[1h], 24 * 3600) < 0 and ON (instance, device, mountpoint) node_filesystem_readonly == 0
    for: 2m
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: Host disk will fill in 24 hours (instance {{ $labels.instance }})

      description: Filesystem is predicted to run out of space within the next 24 hours at current write rate\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}

Same rule using "node_filesystem_free_bytes" will fire when disk fills for non-root users and similar in github also.
Have a look at this Prometheus-style UI for your alerts, recording rules, and Alertmanager.
